# Two objects inheriting same parent have swapped attributes

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm currently writing a swarm AI program that simulates wide-scale combat in Java.  I'm using an abstract class, AIUnit, as defined below:

```
public abstract class AIUnit
{
private int health;

protected AIUnit(int health)
{
    this.health = health;
}

public abstract void Move();    //Move unit
public abstract void Attack(AIUnit unit);   //Attack unit in front
public abstract void Send(int freq,int msg);    //Send message on frequency
public abstract void Recv();    //Receive message

public int GetHealth()
{
    return health;
}

public void TakeDamage(String name)
{
    --health;
    System.out.println(name+" took damage!  Health remaining: "+health);
    if (health == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(name+" is dead!");
        this.Die();
    }
}

public void Die()
{
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

There are two AI classes, as of yet: Barbarian and Medic, as defined below:
Barbarian:

```
public class Barbarian extends AIUnit
{   
private String name = "Barbarian";
public Barbarian(int health)
{
    super(health);
}
//Move unit
public void Move()
{
}
//Attack unit in front
public void Attack(AIUnit unit)
{
    unit.TakeDamage(name);
}
//Send message on frequency
public void Send(int freq, int msg)
{
}
//Receive message
public void Recv()
{
}
}
```

and Medic:

```
public class Medic extends AIUnit
{
private String name = "Medic";
public Medic(int health)
{
    super(health);
}
//Move unit
public void Move()
{
}
//Attack unit in front
public void Attack(AIUnit unit)
{
    unit.TakeDamage(name);
}
//Send message on frequency
public void Send(int freq, int msg)
{
}
//Receive message
public void Recv()
{
}
//Heal unit
public void Heal(AIUnit unit)
{
}
}
```

Note that the two classes are mostly identical, differing only in their names and that the Medic class has an unimplemented Heal method.

Now, when testing a simple Attack method with the following Main class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main
{
public static int barbhealth = 3;
public static int medhealth = 2;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int whoAttacks = rand.nextInt() % 2;
    Barbarian b = new Barbarian(barbhealth);
    Medic m = new Medic(medhealth);
    for(;;whoAttacks = rand.nextInt() % 2)
    {
        if (whoAttacks == 0)
            m.Attack(b);
        else
            b.Attack(m);
    }
}
}
```

I get odd results.  For some reason, the Barbarian, who should have 3 health, starts with 2, and the Medic, who should have 2 health, starts with 3.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Create a minimal self contained test case that exhibits the odd behaviour.

Comment: Update: the object calling Attack() is taking the damage. :/

Comment: It would be nice if there is a mechanism to follow the program doing his work step by step to see what happens ...

Comment: Rename the function `TakeDamage()` to `TakeDamageFrom()` and the paramater `name` to `attacker` and you will yourself figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're printing the wrong name. Given

```
m.Attack(b);
```

and

```
//Attack unit in front
public void Attack(AIUnit unit)
{
    unit.TakeDamage(name);
}

public void TakeDamage(String name)
{
    --health;
    System.out.println(name+" took damage!  Health remaining: "+health);
    if (health == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(name+" is dead!");
        this.Die();
    }
}
```

`this` is a `Medic`. So `unit` is a `Barbarian` and `name` is `"Medic"`. So it looks like `Medic` is taking the damage when really it is the `Barbarian`.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  Got it.  Accepting your answer as soon as I can.